# Android XML layout attribute android:layout_toLeftOf

Tags: android, layout

I want to know whether the XML layout attribute `android:layout_toLeftOf` is specific to a layout or it can be used with any layout? Please help.

Regards & Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is specific to the [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_toLeftOf).

Comment: Is it also true that it will not cause any problem if used with other layouts (even mistakenly).

Comment: I have not encountered any issues yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this attribute is used with RelativeLayout. Although, using it with other layouts will not cause any errors but it will have no effect.